# Retrieving the _id in mongoDB from node.js express

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I want to get the `_id` from the user trying to login. I was wondering if I was able to search by username and get the `_id` or any other way to get the `_id` from the user trying to log in. The problem that I am getting is that `req.body.userID = null`. I think it is because the data I send from my mobile app to the server, I do not send a `userID`. I just do not know how to get the `_id` to either send it or obtain it.

Here is what I have:

```
if(bool){
    var err = false;
    var handleError = function(e){
    if(err){
      err = true;
      var eDoc = {};
      eDoc.errorCode = 1;
      eDoc.error = e;
      console.log(eDoc);
    }
  }
  var userID = req.body.userID || handleError("no userID");
  console.log(req.body.userID);
  if(userID != null){
    if(!err){
      tokens.db = req.db;
      tokens.session.create(3, userID, function(token){
        res.send('1');
      });
    }else{
      console.log('Token err = true');
    }
  }else{
    console.log('Creator token = null');
    res.send('0');
  }
}else{
    res.send('0');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is, use express-session to save the logged in user information. So, here is how it will work.

1. When user successfully logs in, save the user information in a express session at the server side.
2. Now, you won't have to worry about sending the user id from your frontend, because the user info is already present in a session at server code.

Please let me know if you need to know the steps on implementing this.

Comment: The reason I am staying clear from sessions is because they are insure. I am creating my own token communication system between client and server side.